# Users Value Won't Store In Array

Tags: java, arrays

So I have this assignment called "ChangeUp" and I have to randomize an index then add in the users value in the array. I already did most of the code, unless I did it wrong, but I just can't add the users number in the index.

> Create an empty int array of size 6. Create a method called
> populateArray that will pass an array, use random class to choose a
> random index and prompt the user to enter a value, store the value in
> the array. Note: Generate 6 random index numbers in an attempt to fill
> the array.  Create a method called printArray that prints the contents
> of the array using the for each enhanced loop.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ChangeUp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] hairline = new int[6];
        populateArray(hairline);
        printArray(hairline);
    }

    private static void populateArray(int[] hairline){
        Random TNT = new Random();
        Scanner kirby = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.format("Enter %d numbers:\n", hairline.length);
        int goo = TNT.nextInt(6);
        int user = kirby.nextInt();
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < hairline.length-1; i++){
            hairline[i] = TNT.nextInt(6);
        }
    }

    private static void printArray(int... hairline){
        System.out.print("{");
        for(int i : hairline){
            System.out.print( i  + " " );
        }
        System.out.println("}");
    }
}
```

Comment: You *probably* (the instructions are not super-clear) need to put most of the populateArray method inside of the for loop, everything below creation of the Random and Scanner objects. And then get the user input with each iteration of the loop, placing it into the random index position. Be careful to check for duplicate random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed was the for loop condition

> for(i = 0; i < hairline.length-1; i++)

The loop will only go from 0 to 4.
Second, you aren't doing anything with the user variable.

The instructions seem somewhat ambiguous, but taking it literally, you want to generate a random number 6 times. For each random number, have the user enter a number and store that number in the position of the array that is the random number.  E.g. random number = 2, user input = 50, then array[2] = 50.  There is no guarantee every position will get a value, but maybe that is intended?

It sounds like this is an assignment of some kind so I probably shouldn't be posting a solution, but your code only puts random numbers (between 0 and 5) into the first 5 positions of the array.

Comment: so do I do something like for(i = 0; i <= user; i++)

Comment: The loop condition determines when the loop should end.  The instructions are to generate 6 random numbers, so the loop should execute 6 times.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! I was overthinking it so bad because the question was confusing.

import java.util.*;

public class ChangeUp {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] hairline = new int[6]; 
    populateArray(hairline);
    printArray(hairline);
}
private static void populateArray(int[] hairline){
    Random TNT = new Random();
    Scanner kirby = new Scanner(System.in); 
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        int randIndex = TNT.nextInt(6);
        System.out.print("Enter the value of index " + randIndex + ": ");
        hairline[randIndex] = kirby.nextInt();
    }
}
private static void printArray(int... hairline){
    for(int i : hairline){
        System.out.print(i + "  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

}